# How do I change my title action bar (Fragment)?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer and I want one of my menu's title action bar be change, how will I change it? By the way, I'm using a Fragment in my java file.

Here's my code:

_7_ViewClient_Feedback.java

```
public class _7_ViewClient_Feedback extends Fragment {
    View myView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity__7__view_client_feedback, container, false);
        return myView;


    }

}
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title:"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:width="325dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
    android:height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/feedbacktitle"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_submitfb"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textSize="9pt"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/buttonColor"
    android:textAllCaps="false"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```